# Bit comparison code, would like help understanding it

Tags: c, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I have been looking at an example piece of code for a binary counter, I am having difficulty fully understanding what is taking place within the for loop switching each of the ledOnOffState using the bitwise operation.

It is the (i & 1), (i & 2), and (i & 4) that I'm having a little trouble with at the moment, for each of the i numbers counting from 0 - 7.

I think what is happening is for each of the i decimals within the loop their binary values are being used for the operation against the binary values for the 1, 2, and 4 in the () for the ledOnOffState. But I not quite sure exactly what these parts are doing. For instance when i = 3, 011, what is happening for each of  the (3 & 1), (3 & 2) and (3 & 4), to produce 1, 1, and 0 respectively for binary value of 011?

```
bool led1OnOffState; // true = 1 = ON (HIGH), false = 0 = OFF (LOW)
bool led2OnOffState;
bool led3OnOffState;

int iterations = 2;

for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++)
{
     // a for loop that counts from 0 to 7
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        // check to see if the 1, 2, and 4 bits are set for the current counter number
        led1OnOffState = (i & 1); // check for binary bit value 1 = true (1) or false (0)
        led2OnOffState = (i & 2); // check for binary bit value 2
        led3OnOffState = (i & 4); // check for binary bit value 4

        printf("The decimal %d is %d%d%d in binary\n", i, led3OnOffState, led2OnOffState, led1OnOffState);
```

If it is only comparing one bit for instance the 2^0 bits for the (3 & 1) and the 2^1 bits for the (3 & 2) and the 2^2 bits for the (3 & 4) in these cases it would makes sense to me, as it results in 1, 1, 0 respectively.

But I suspect that is not quite the case, my other thought is that perhaps it is performing 3 bitwise AND operations on each of the bits and if any of them are true it changes the ledOnOffState value to TRUE if none are true it is changed to FALSE.

I tried the code using a ledOnOffState = (i & 3) and the results led me to think the latter case may be true, as only the 0 and 4 decimal values were 0 but all other came up as 1s.

Comment: `(i & x)` expressions are getting *non-zero* values while the respective *bits* in `i` are non-zero. Since these are assigned to `bool` variables, they can only have a non zero value of `1` or `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-zero integer assigned to a `bool` gets implicitly converted to `1`/`true`, otherwise `0`/`false`. The masks 1, 2 and 4 respectively simply refers to the 3 least significant bits of the value, binary `001`, `010`, `100`. If the masked bit is set, each expression will evaluate to `true`.

This means that this code generates a truth table according to this:

```
i     LED1 LED2 LED3
0      0    0    0
1      1    0    0
2      0    1    0
3      1    1    0
4      0    0    1
...
```

That is, the code is simply doing a binary count-up and spreading it across 3 bool variables.

A more conventional approach, as done in real-world embedded systems, is to route all 3 LEDs to the same port using pin 0,1,2, then simply do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  PORT = i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but could you perhaps expand on what is happening with the masks in relation to i value for selecting whether the LED is set to 1 or 0? Is it just looking at that single bit value for the 1, 2, or 4 within the 3 LSB, when performing the AND operation? Or is it taking all 3 LSBs into accounts? If instead of 1, 2 or 4 we replace the number with 3, so the binary is 011, and the mask now contains 2 ON values, what is happening within the code to determine whether the state is ON or OFF?

Comment: @Dave `(i & 1)` means bit 0, `(i & 2)` means bit 1 and `(i & 4)` means bit 2. That's the whole point of bit masking. The operand `i` is of course "the whole of i" but the mask is just a single bit in each case. It's more common to write bit masks as hex, but it doesn't change anything in this case (0x01, 0x2, 0x04). Masking with 3 doesn't make any sense, since the purpose here is to create a binary counter.

Comment: thank you, I am aware that masking with 3 makes no sense in this case of the binary counter, but the point of my question is not the binary counter itself. The focus of my question and what I want to understand is what is happening in the (i & x) part of the code, to make it either 0 or 1, this is why I ask about the case of (i & 3) as this would I hope clarify it for me. What happens within the operation if two bits are 1, does the mask require both 1s to match for the & to make it true or just one? If I used (i & 7) would it output 1 for each 1-7 value and 0 for 0?

Comment: @Dave The whole point with this code is to mask with just 1 bit. Any non-zero result will become `true`. Study bitwise AND.

Comment: I asked the question because I was having trouble understanding the bitwise AND within this bool operation and was hoping for some clarification. Again while the point of the code is the mask, my question is not about the whole code, just this one operation within it, I had hoped this point would have be clear to readers of my question, trying to illustrate that with the (i & 3), perhaps I included too much code. However from your "any non-zero result will become true" comment, has helped everything click into place for me, so thank you. If anything is non-zero the result is TRUE.